# FortiClient VPN API

Tags: c#, vpn

I am trying to access FortiClient VPN by using its API.

I am able to create a VPN connection using FortiClient's own GUI. By using the API I am not able to get any results from existing connections.

The API documentation is available at: http://docs.fortinet.com/uploaded/files/1199/FortiClient_Admin_Guide.pdf p.63

I am trying to get the list of available tunnels like so, with no results:

```
using System;
using FCCOMINTDLLLib;
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FCCOMINTDLLLib.VPN vpn = new VPNClass();
            var tunnels = vpn.GetTunnelList();
        }
    }
}
```

How to populate variable `tunnels` with a list of connections, that should be returned by calling `GetTunnelList();`

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @leiit unfortunately not. I do not remember solving this. Maybe you could get help by contacting their support. As this was over 3 years ago I do not even remember what was the workaround that I used.